# Pick one: Logic or Logical Fallacy?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently there are both a tag for [logic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) and [logical-fallacy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-fallacy). Which one should be used? Is it necessary that both should be used?

Comment: Personally, I think a corollary situation exists with the vaccines vs. anti-vaccine tag (cf. http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28/pick-one-vaccines-or-anti-vaccination/30#30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not equivalent, [logical-fallacy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-fallacy) is a specific subset of [logic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic). They are not synonyms.

Comment: I never said they were; they are not equivalent. But is logical-fallacy going to prove useful enough to have it's own tag? That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Logic. Logical fallacies are faulty logic. Logic will show that they are.